# In C, a function that should only return the literals 1 or 0 is returning 2147483646?

Tags: c, overflow

This code is supposed to detect whether or not an integer overflow will occur:

```
int tadd_ok(int x, int y) {
    if ((x < 0) && (y < 0)) {
        if ((INT_MIN - x) > y) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if ((x > 0) && (y > 0)) {
        if ((INT_MAX - x) < y) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else
        return 1;
}
```

With inputs:

```
        printf("Check TADD\n");
        printf("1 + 1: %d\n", tadd_ok(1, 1));
        printf("1 + 2: %d\n", tadd_ok(1, 2));
        printf("-1 + -1: %d\n", tadd_ok(-1, -1));
        printf("-1 + 1: %d\n", tadd_ok(-1, 1));
        printf("1 + -1: %d\n", tadd_ok(1, -1));
        printf("INT_MAX + 1: %d\n", tadd_ok(INT_MAX, 1));
        printf("INT_MAX + -1: %d\n", tadd_ok(INT_MAX, -1));
        printf("INT_MAX + 2: %d\n", tadd_ok(INT_MAX, 2));
        printf("INT_MIN + -1: %d\n", tadd_ok(INT_MIN, -1));
        printf("INT_MIN + 1: %d\n", tadd_ok(INT_MIN, 1));
```

I get outputs:

```
Check TADD
1 + 1: 2147483646
1 + 2: 2147483646
-1 + -1: 1
-1 + 1: 1
1 + -1: 1
INT_MAX + 1: 0
INT_MAX + -1: 1
INT_MAX + 2: 0
INT_MIN + -1: 0
INT_MIN + 1: 1
```

For some reason when two positive numbers are input, some how `INT_MAX - 1` is getting returned. I'm not sure what's going on here. My only guess is that I'm causing undefined behavior in the test, but If I'm understanding correctly, `(INT_MAX - x)` should be the only questionable test, and as long as `x` is positive, which is should be from the prior test, this should not cause overflow.

Comment: Do you get  warnings when compiling it? You should be getting some. You have paths not returning values.

Comment: Does `(INT_MAX - x) < y`? If not, then you don't have a return statement. What happens if you don't have a return statement?

Comment: Wouldn't `INT_MIN - 1` "Underflow" ?

Comment: I usually do that kind of function like this: `int foo(...) { int ret = 0; /*change ret according to some conditions*/; return ret; }` ... of course the elided code must be comprehensive or some errors will pass through (as is the case in your function)

Comment: I notice that the issue seems to be with the else statement. If I change that to just the return statement by itself it works as expected, and now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Advice: always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` (or equivalent), this will help you detect many mistakes during compilation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok I understand now, and that makes sense why taking out the else statement worked. I didn't receive and warnings from the compiler, I'm using gcc (SUSE Linux) 7.4.0, should it have gave me a warning?

Answer (score 0):

You fell off the end of the function, returning a random number. I think you need to change `else return 1;` to `return 1;`

In C, a function that returns something other than void either ends with a return statement or an infinite loop. For historical reasons, a function with a return type of int does not yield an error, but an unspecified value should the return value be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your function: the function does not hit a `return` statement if `x > 0 && y > 0` but `(INT_MAX - x) >= y)`. Any modern compiler will issue a diagnostic for this if correctly configured: always ask for most warnings and address them (eg: `gcc -Wall Werror`).

Here is a modified version:

```c
int tadd_ok(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
        if ((INT_MIN - x) > y)
            return 0;
    }
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
        if ((INT_MAX - x) < y)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And here is a simplified version:

```c
int tadd_ok(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0) 
        return y >= INT_MIN - x;
    else
        return y <= INT_MAX - x;
}
```